# laravel, basic instalation, redirect give me back a 500 Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vhosts, apache2.4

I have make a basic instalation of Laravel 5.6.5 with composer, and also I have added socialite plugin.

I have read some stackoverflow question, but I dont't get it works.

**If I run laravel with `php artisan serve` it works**, but If I try to use the local Apache (2.4.18) It give me back this error:

```
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.079971 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6892] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080019 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6892] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080489 2018] [core:error] [pid 6892] [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080495 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3628): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00121: r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080497 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080499 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080501 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080503 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080504 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080506 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080508 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080509 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080511 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.080512 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6892] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35198] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134407 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6894] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134426 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 6894] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134607 2018] [core:error] [pid 6894] [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134612 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3628): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00121: r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134614 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134616 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134618 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134619 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134625 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134627 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134629 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134630 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134632 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /public/favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
[Wed Feb 28 19:19:21.134634 2018] [core:debug] [pid 6894] core.c(3635): [client 127.0.0.1:35200] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /favicon.ico, referer: http://laravel.local/
```

This is my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel.local

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/oskar/Webapps/Laravel/twitter_follow/public
        <Directory   /home/oskar/Webapps/Laravel/twitter_follow/public>
        AllowOverride All
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                <Limit GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
                        Require all granted
                </Limit>

                <LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
                        Require all denied
                </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel_local.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel_local.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this as vhost. by looking at the trace it's moke likely a configuration issue

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName laravel.local
  DocumentRoot /home/oskar/Webapps/Laravel/twitter_follow/public

  <Directory /home/oskar/Webapps/Laravel/twitter_follow/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel-local-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel-local-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hello ainmme, with this configuration I get this error:
La página laravel.local no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
HTTP ERROR 500,

But I don't have any error in log file.